# Adding an arraylist results to a text file

Tags: java, dynamic, arraylist

In this program, it will run for 20 iterations. Each iteration is completed when a terminal state is reached. I want to get the results for all 20 iterations to write to a text file but at the moment only the last iteration will write to a text file.

I thought by creating two arraylists and adding the the variables "numsteps" (which hold the number of steps in an iteration) and "rewards" (which holds to the total of the reward for that iteration) to the two arraylists  '"steps"' and '"rewards"', it would automatically insert all of the values to for each iteration to the arraylists and then enter the arraylists into a text file.

But at the moment it will only insert the last iteration of numsteps and rewards into a text file.

Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
            if (nextState.isTerminal()) {
         //storing total number of steps and total of rewards int x and y
        double reward = ((GridEnvir) env).total;
        int numsteps = (int) ((GridEnvir) env).numStepsInTrial;

        //create array for number of steps in trial  = steps
        ArrayList<Integer> steps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        steps.add(numsteps);

        //create array for rewards in trial  = rewards
        ArrayList<Double> rewards = new ArrayList<Double>();
        rewards.add(reward);


        try {
          // method to write to a text file.   
          write(steps, rewards, 20);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("does work");
        }

        /// printing out to the console window each time the nextState.isTerminal() condition is reached
        System.out.println("\n Found goal in " + x + " steps "+ " total reward " + y);

        System.out.println(agt);
    }

}
```

This next method writes to a text file with the results.

```
public static void write(ArrayList<Integer> numsteps, ArrayList<Double> reward,
        int episode) throws IOException {

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(
             // not actual (this part of code is hidden)
            "results.txt");


    int y[] = new int[episode];

    pw.write("NumSteps" + "\t " + "reward" + "\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        for (int a : numsteps) {
            for (Double b : reward)

                pw.write(a + "\t\t " + b + "\n");
        }// }

        pw.close();
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    for (int a : numsteps) {
        for (Double b : reward)
            pw.write(a + "\t\t " + b + "\n");
    }
    pw.close();
 }
```

So in first iteration, it will write to file both numsteps and reward. But once its written, when i is 0, you close the stream and then for i as 1 you try writing to close stream and which is the reason why you see data written just once in the file.

Try removing `pw.close()` after the for loop with i as variable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I tried it but now it writes out the last result 20 times.

Comment: what do you mean by last result 20 times? if your list numsteps has 1, 2 and reward has 3, 4 then it would print 1,3.. 1,4.. 2,3..2,4.. these 4 lines 20 times..

Comment: what i mean is the last iteration might have 15 number of steps and reward 4, and its write out this result 20 times, (15, 4) (15 4) etc. instead of getting all of the result e.g (35, 23) (20 ,20) (15 ,4)( 11, 0 )

Comment: Can you try for 2 numbers in both and see if that works? If it fails for 15, 4 numbers than i would expect it to come up even with 2/3 numbers. please try.